# Native UI Toolkit for Desktop, Mobile, and Web

Tags: gratis, open-source, gui, cross-platform, mobile

I'm looking for a cross-platform native GUI toolkit that supports desktop (Windows, Mac, Linux), mobile (Android, iOS), and web browser, without embedding web technologies. It should use native controls on web (unlike Qt), and preferably also on the other platforms.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any solutions that use native controls on all platforms, but I found a few that at least don't try to do their own text rendering on Web, so they should work with a screen reader:

- [Flutter](https://flutter.dev) ([Dart language](https://dart.dev)) - Desktop and Web support is currently experimental, but it works
- [HaxeUI](http://haxeui.org) ([Haxe language](https://haxe.org)) - Very portable, but oddly uses Javascript in some places
- [OpenFL](https://openfl.org) + [Feathers UI](https://feathersui.com) ([Haxe language](https://haxe.org)) - Feathers UI support for OpenFL is currently alpha, but it works